# "I feel my heart go boom " or "goes boom"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verb-agreement

Which one below is correct?:

> 1. I feel my heart go boom
> 2. I feel my heart goes boom

And why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Both can be correct, but they mean different things. Please remember to include full context, as well as to demonstrate your initial attempts at your own research, when posting questions here. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Did you mean [*boom-diddy-boom-diddy-boom diddy-boom-diddy-boom-boom-boom*?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3A7B6qtUpU)

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible.

"I feel my heart go boom" is parallel to "I see him go," "I hear it ring," etc., where the last verb (in each example) is an [infinitive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/hear-see-etc-object-infinitive-or-ing).

"I feel my heart goes boom" is parallel to "I see he is going," an ellipsis for "I feel **that** my heart goes boom." Here, obviously, the last verbs are no longer infinitives.

The first alternative seem more likely to be the intended message.

(Soon they'll be gathering in the comments to dock me a few points and whisper "irrealis" to each other; but there it is, I've done it, I've ventured into a discussion of grammar!)